# What made *silphium* difficult to domesticate?

Tags: extinction, agriculture

I tried this question at Worldbuilding SE, and was told that perhaps this place would give me a better chance at an answer. So, leaving aside the worldbuilding aspects of the issue, I am interested in the now-extinct plant called silphium, which was widely used as a contraceptive in the Classic world, and was overharvested into extinction at the beggining of the Middle Age, being apparently non-domesticable.

So, why exactly was it non-domesticable? Was it actually non-domesticable, or its domestication, like that of strawberries, just depended on some techonolgical innovation that was not available at the time it become extinct? If it was really impossible to domesticate, what measures could be taken, in a pre-industrial society, barring it not being used as contraceptive, to at least protect it from extinction?

More generally, what factors lead a plant to being non-domesticable?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silphium#Identity_and_extinction): `we cannot even accurately identify the plant we cannot know for certain whether it is extinct.` and `The cause of silphium's supposed extinction is not entirely known`. Because we know nothing about this plant (but the name people gave it in the middle age), it impossible to make much speculation. I am voting to close for this reason.

Comment: The factors that make *anything* hard to domesticate rely largely on factors that make it difficult to artificially select domestic traits. Perhaps it was long-lived or germinated infrequently, or needed a different kind of space or environment than the people at the time were giving it, or had some other unseen condition that civilization at the time wasn't able to rescue. For example, it's hard to domesticate elephants because they only birth every 5 years and sexually mature after about 15 years. By the time you select for a trait, you may very well have died many times over!

Comment: Have you found _any_ reliable sources for this plant's existance? The wikipedia page seems to be from that era when wikipedia wasn't exactly trustworthy... Note that there are many extant species going by the name of "Silphium" [[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silphium_(genus)) ; [article](http://www.amjbot.org/content/87/4/565.full.pdf+html)].